# (Windows Forms) Button only available if bool is true

Tags: forms, button, boolean

Is it possible to set a button so that it is only clickable if a bool is true?
This isn't my actual code but:

```
bool details_accepted = false;

public bool check_bank_details()
{
    //this is simplified it's actually using an SQL query
    if (bank_details = "123456789")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

if (check_bank_details == true)
{
    //CODE FOR SETTING BUTTON TO CLICKABLE
}
else if (check_bank_details == false)
{
    //Code making Button not clickable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the Enabled property

```
Button1.Enabled = check_bank_details();
```